# How to get system Time settings property through an UWP Xamarin application

Tags: datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin application and I need to check whether the Date&Time setting has enabled the "Set Automatically" property or not.

I need to validate the current Date&Time uses NTP time or not?

Images- [Type-Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxdfz.png) [Start property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFqlL.png)
[Normal Date seetings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EyAy.png)

Steps for accessing NTP through the registry as follows(Normal windows not from APP)

1- Press the Windows logo key + R to open the Run box. Type Regedit and hit Enter.

2- When the Registry Editor opens, navigate to the following key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters to check Type property value is NTP or NoSync

3- In order to enable or disable “Set Time Zone Automatically” in Windows 10, navigate to the following key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\tzautoupdate

4- Double-click the 32-bit DWORD “Start” in the right pane. Set its value data to 3 if you want to make Windows 10 set time zone automatically. If you want to disable “Set Time Zone Automatically” in Windows 10, just set the value to 4.

I need to validate either 2 or 3 values through Xamarin UWP apps, whether The date&time setting is set to Automatically or not.

I am attaching the screenshots
Please refer to this [link](https://www.top-password.com/blog/enable-or-disable-set-time-zone-automatically-in-windows-10/) for how we can get the Date&Time settings through Normal windows, I need to check this one through Xamarin UWP application.

If it is enabled I need to perform an operation otherwise I need to display an Alert that showing to "change the Date&Time setting and try again later".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to validate either 2 or 3 values through Xamarin UWP apps,
> whether The date&time setting is set to Automatically or not.

Actually, we can't access Registry within UWP platform. UWP runs in sandbox, and it has not permission to access registry. But we could use the **Windows Desktop Extensions** for the Universal Windows Platform to launch a “runFullTrust” Win32 application that acts as a Background process to read from the Registry. And pass the value back with UWP AppService. For more detail you could refer stefanwick's U*WP with Desktop Extension* blog.

And if you just want to know whether The date&time setting is set to Automatically or not.

You could use [`LaunchUriAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync) method to launch [`ms-settings:dateandtime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#time-and-language) uri. Then check whether **Set time automatically** is on or off.

```
bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:dateandtime));
```